# O CSS não está funcionando em nenhum navegador do meu PC

Tags: css

Boa noite, tenho que fazer um TCC para finalizar meu curso, porém o CSS do meu código não funciona em nenhum navegador. Ele só funcionar se eu puxo ele online da nuvem:

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Se eu puxo ele offline do meu pc, não funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Eu testei puxar ele offline pelo pc da minha escola e funcionou, eu acho que deve ser alguma coisa no meu pc. Seu alguém tiver alguma ideia do que seria, poderiam me ajudar por favor?

obs: não é o framework, pois já testei o Uikit também e foi o mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu não sei mas tenta usar so .css ao inves de .min.css

Comment: Qual é a URL que aparece no navegador quando você abre esse html nele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver o problema, eu teria que adicionar os 2 pontos (..) para mostrar que a pasta "css" estava dentro de outras pastas. Desculpa galera, era uma coisa simples, mas eu fiquei nervoso por causa da pressão do TCC kkkkkkkkk

Eis aqui a resposta:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a permissão do arquivo / pasta, talvez não tenha permissão suficiente.

**Em linux (Debian, Ubuntu, etc..**

Permissão recomendada para diretórios (pastas) é 755

```
sudo chmod 755 /nome_da_pasta
```

Já para arquivos é 644

```
sudo chmod 644 /nome_do_arquivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que sua pasta não está dando permissão à acesso. Se o endereço e o nome do arquivo da certo.

Faz assim, clica com o botão direito na tua pasta css vai em propriedades e na aba segurança clica em "Editar"

Vai abrir uma nova janela, clica em "Adicionar" digita "todos" seleciona o usuario "Todos" na lista e dá um OK. Nas caixinhas de baixo ativa o "Controle Total". Dá um ok e fecha. Faz um teste para ver.

Comment: Obrigado, eu consegui resolver. Era um problema na digitação do código.

Comment: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

Comment: Ah sim, que bom que resolveu, pelo caminho imaginei que estava na raiz mesmo se não já tinha dado a dica heheh. Mas que bom que resolveu.